# Dual boot partitioning problem on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a 1.5 TB HDD. I am learning Linux and I don't know Linux much.
I would like to divide my HDD into 3 parts. 
1) Windows 8.1 (NTFS)
2) Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
3) Storage which can be accessed by Windows and Ubuntu (NTFS)

As I searched and understood from internet, I should have installed Windows first, then Ubuntu in order to make the storage can be accessed by both operating systems.

My HDD was MBR. I turned it into GPT by installing Windows 8.1 on it. While installing Windows, I made 3 partitions. 196 gb for Windows, 100 gb for Ubuntu, rest of them for storage.

Windows was working fine. Than i started installing ubuntu.
First, I created a 250 mb partition for efi (that's what they told on internet in order to provide UEFI setup)
Than 12 GBs of Swap area for allowing hibernate (I have 8 Gigs of ram.)
Rest of them was / root partition.

I installed Ubuntu. In the end, it asked for restarting. I did it. BIOS can see ubuntu in the boot order but, I doesn't boot and asks me to insert a bootable device.

Than I installed Ubuntu again, but this time I created a /home partition too.

[The current partition status on my HDD is like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KovG.png)
I didn't understand what I should do and, I am looking for help.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: AMD FX-8320, ASUS M5A97 R2.0, ASUS GTX 760 2GB, 8 Gigs of RAM
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26514920/ I am not sure if it is ppa version, I followed this link while waiting answer https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/
I am following your link now.

Comment: Do not know if any unique issues with AMD. Your nVidia card will need nomodeset boot parameter both for install & first boot or until you install nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. did you install in UEFI boot mode? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I followed your link's instructions, got this link http://paste.ubuntu.com/26514986/
I don't known anything about nomodeset parameter. I am starting to search it on internet now. I can't boot Ubuntu on HDD, now I am using pendrive's try ubuntu option, if I find some instructions about nomodeset parameter and if I apply them on the pendrive live cd, would it be OK?
Yes, I think I did install in UEFI mode. I checked it by [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS it said UEFI

Comment: Sir, I rebooted and GRUB is visible at startup now. I don't known what happened but I think boot-repair solved the problem. Now Windows is not visible on GRUB, also I can't access the 1.1 TB storage partition. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You now have Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode on MBR where normally gpt is used. But Windows is BIOS boot which requires MBR partitioning. And Boot-Repair says Windows is in unsafe condition which usually is fast start up/hibernation is on. And it says UEFI has Secure Boot on, which means you never could boot Windows in BIOS mode. Also boot flag must be on sda1 to boot Windows in BIOS mode, but on efi partition to boot in UEFI mode. Better to have both systems in same boot mode.

Comment: I understand that, I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode but, I installed Windows in BIOS mode (old type, not UEFI). I am going to wipe all hdd and install Windows in UEFI mode, after that, I will install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. If I didn't understand correctly, could you point where I am wrong, please?

Comment: Now I have installed both Windows and Ubuntu with UEFI installation. Now I can boot into both of them but, I can't boot Windows on GRUB. I have to choose what partition to be booted on startup using F8 key. While I was installing Ubuntu, at the "Device for bootloader installation" section, I choose the efi partition which I created for Ubuntu, Windows' efi partition was existing in another partition too. Should I should have choosed Windows' bootloader partition?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. That means chkdsk not required and no hibernation. And fast start up is hibernation, so it must be off. And Windows updates will turn fast start up back on, so then you have to directly boot Windows to turn it back off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  You really should only have one ESP - efi system partition per device/drive. Some brands have a second FAT32 partition with .efi files for system utilities, but it does not have boot flag, so not ESP. They may change that when you boot system utilities.

Comment: Sir, I think, I've solved the problem with your help. Thank you very much.